# How can I load a snowflake table using Pyspark and the date column of my Dataframe should reflect as TIMESTAMP_LTZ format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

If I want to write a Dataframe to snowflake table, considering the table is already not existing in snowflake and also the timestamp column which I have in my Dataframe should reflect as TIMESTAMP_LTZ format in snowflake while storing.

Note: I don't to alter that timestamp data format to TIMESTAMP_LTZ in snowflake, I want everything to happen in my spark code itself.

EDIT:

The behaviour I'm seeing is that the snowflake table has a datatype of TIMESTAMP_NTZ

Comment: What code do you currently have? What problem are you having with it? Note that datatypes like `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` do not have a format, they are just dates. You can format it when you present it if you like

Comment: I simply write the respective Dataframe to snowflake having timestamp which is CST format but this timestamp format is treated as TIMESTAMP_NTZ by snowflake. I want snowflake to treat this as TIMESTAMP_LTZ instead of timestamp_ntz . I want to know, how can we achieve this from our spark code itself without touching snowflake. Note: the Dataframe which I store to snowflake is not existing and using spark itself i create that.

Comment: It helps to include all the info in the original question - i.e. explain the behaviour you are actually seeing. I edited your question to add this but please add and additional info such as sample data. Does this page help? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#label-spark-timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The behaviour I'm seeing is that the snowflake table has a datatype of TIMESTAMP_NTZ

The observance follows the default behaviour described in Snowflake's [Spark Connector documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#working-with-timestamps-and-time-zones):

> "The default timestamp data type mapping is TIMESTAMP_NTZ (no time zone), so you must explicitly set the TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING parameter to use TIMESTAMP_LTZ."

The `TIMESTAMP` data type mapping in the Spark Connector will map to `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` underlying type instead of `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` if it has been explicitly specified it as a session level parameter (`TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING`) prior to executing CREATE/INSERT operations.

*Session level* parameters [can be expressed in Spark code](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#passing-snowflake-session-parameters-as-options-for-the-connector) and don't require altering any settings permanently on the account. Simply add it as an option in the map of options passed when interacting with Snowflake in the Spark code. A simple example is below:

```
sfOptions += ("TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING" -> "TIMESTAMP_LTZ")
// Pass this adjusted sfOptions to the .options(…) when writing the DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue resolved by add the below befor the snowflake read action:

```
java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

@Harish J has already explained the reason, also same mentioned in the Snowflake Documentation  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html.